# Remove Nth Node From End of Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error

Given the head of a linked list, remove the nth node from the end of the list and return its head.

Alongside the two pointer solution, I also tried the two pass solution which is you traverse till the end of the list and find the number of nodes and then you you come back to the (n-1)th node and then change the next pointer of the node to the (n+1)th node. \

But I am getting an error that says "member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'"

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
```

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        int count = 0;

        ListNode *ptr = head;              //Lets say the linked list is 1->2->3->4->5
                                           //I have ignored some edge cases ignoring those test cases
        while (ptr != nullptr) {
            count++;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

        int remove = count - n -1;

        ptr = head;

        while (count > 0) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
            count--;
        }
   
        ptr->next = ptr->next->next; //compiler showing runtime error here

        return head;
    }
};      error : "member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'"
```

Comment: There is no check in your code for `n`, it should be smaller then the length of your list. And what happens if `ptr->next` is a nullptr? (e.g. remove last item from the list)

Comment: Help yourself visualize the problem by drawing pictures and the rest is plain old book-keeping.

Comment: Also try running your code in a debugger, go over the code step by step and check if it behaves exactly as you had in mind.

Comment: You compute `remove` - but then go ahead and make `count` steps in the second loop. Since `count` is the length of the list, `ptr` is known to be null at the end of that second loop. Finally, you go ahead and dereference that null pointer. Did you mean to actually use `remove` in there somewhere?

Comment: Consider also the case where `n == count-1` and you are expected to remove the head node.

Comment: I found the error as pointed out by @IgorTandetnik, In the final while loop I have by mistake used the 'count' variable instead of the 'remove' variable. The whole purpose of the 'remove' variable is to get to the node that is to be deleted. The 'count' variable is meant to store the length of the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    // Time: O(n) Sapce: O(1)
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        ListNode start = ListNode(0);
        start.next = head;
        
        ListNode* fast = &start;
        ListNode* slow = &start;     

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            fast = fast->next;
    
        while (fast->next) {
            fast = fast->next;
            slow = slow->next;
        }
        
        auto tmp  = slow->next;
        slow->next = slow->next->next;
        
        delete tmp;
        
        return start.next;
    }
};
```

Comment: Works unless `n` is greater than the size of the list.